# Axis2 generated service creates wrong request

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I have generated some java (1.5) WS classes using axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin (1.4.1). When I use these something strange is happening and I simply don't understand what's going on.

The problem is that I call one method, but the actual web service call that happens is a different one.

```
ConfigServiceStub service = new ConfigServiceStub(URL);

ServiceRequest request = new ServiceRequest();
request.setProcessId(processId);
request.setServiceCode(BigInteger.valueOf(113));

service.removeService(request);
```

When I run this code, what actually happens is a web service call to `getServiceDetails`. I don't understand why. The following results in a correct web service call.

```
service.getServiceDetails(request);
```

Is there something about my reuse in the XSD which messes things up, or what is going on here?

---

Here is relevant WSDL and XSD:

**Binding**

```
<operation name="getServiceDetails">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://api.nwn.no/webservices/ProductConfigurator/getServiceDetails" />
    <input><soap:body /></input>
    <output><soap:body /></output>
    <fault name="fault"><soap:fault name="fault" /></fault> 
</operation>

<operation name="removeService">
    <soap:operation soapAction="http://api.nwn.no/webservices/ProductConfigurator/removeService" />
    <input><soap:body /></input>
    <output><soap:body /></output>
    <fault name="fault"><soap:fault name="fault" /></fault>     
</operation>
```

**PortType**

```
<operation name="getServiceDetails">
    <input message="tns:getServiceDetailsRequest" />
    <output message="tns:getServiceDetailsResponse" />
    <fault message="tns:fault" name="fault" />          
</operation>

<operation name="removeService">
    <input message="tns:removeServiceRequest" />
    <output message="tns:removeServiceResponse" />
    <fault message="tns:fault" name="fault" />      
</operation>
```

**Message**

```
<message name="getServiceDetailsRequest">
    <part name="body" element="tns:getServiceDetailsRequest" />
</message>
<message name="getServiceDetailsResponse">
    <part name="body" element="tns:getServiceDetailsResponse" />
</message>

<message name="removeServiceRequest">
    <part name="body" element="tns:removeServiceRequest" />
</message>
<message name="removeServiceResponse">
    <part name="body" element="tns:removeServiceResponse" />
</message>
```

**Schema**

```
<xsd:element name="getServiceDetailsRequest" type="ServiceRequest" />
<xsd:element name="getServiceDetailsResponse" type="ServiceResponse" />

<xsd:element name="removeServiceRequest" type="ServiceRequest" />
<xsd:element name="removeServiceResponse" type="ServiceConfigurationResponse" />

<xsd:complexType name="ProcessRequest">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="processId" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="ServiceRequest">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="ProcessRequest">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="serviceCode" type="ServiceCode" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you determine the generated value for SOAPAction? It should be different.

You should consider not to reuse XML elements for different operations. It is not WS-I compliant. SOAPAction is not mandatory for WS-I compliant services.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use another databinding using the databindingName parameter as described here:

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/maven-plugins/maven-wsdl2code-plugin.html